# Marathon With Private Docker Repo

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I'm having issues pulling from a private docker repo when I add a marathon application. I've tarred my ~/.docker folder (including the docker.config file which contains my login information) and distributed that along to my mesos slaves as /etc/docker.tar.gz (I'm using docker 1.6.2).

I've then added a new marathon app with:

```
dcos marathon add app marathon.json
```

My marathon.json is as follows:

```
{
  "id": "api",
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 1024,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "company/api",
    }
  },
  "args": ["java", "-jar", "api.jar"],
  "uris": [
    "file:///etc/docker.tar.gz"
  ]
}
```

The marathon app never starts, however. In my slave logs I've found the following line:

Container x for executor y of framework z failed to start: Failed to 'docker pull company/api': exit status = exited with status 1 stderr = time="2015-11-12T00:03:57Z" level=fatal msg="Error: image company/api:latest not found"

How can I get this to pull correctly?

Comment: Are you sure Docker is trying to pull from your private repo, not the public one? Can you check the debug output on the Docker daemon to see where the pull request is going?

Comment: the image should probably be "docker.mycompany.com/api:latest"